# Enabling Scroll Bars In Mountain Lion?

Tags: mac, macos

In Mountain Lion scroll bars are turned off by default, and are only seen if **actively scrolling**.

How do you enable them, so that they are seen all the time ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See screenshot. Change the radio button for `Show Scroll Bars` to `Always`. To access this screen, go to `System Preferences -> General`.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

### Terminal Command

Alternatively, if you like Terminal commands (for scripting or BetterTouchTool gestures), you can set scroll bars to always be shown with the following command:

```
defaults write -g AppleShowScrollBars -string Always
```

To reset this, you can use the following command:

```
defaults write -g AppleShowScrollBars -string WhenScrolling
```

You may have to restart the app (or Finder: `killall -HUP Finder`) for the change to take effect.

### Per App Setting

As well as being set globally, these Terminal commands can be used to change the scroll bars **specifically per app**.

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal AppleShowScrollBars -string Always
```

<sup>Replace `com.apple.Terminal` with the bundle identifier of the app that you want to change.</sup>

Comment: You definitely like your Terminal commands, Applescripts & Automations :)

Comment: @grarside For the sake of simplicity (or for people who know nothing about Terminal Commands etc, whichever way you look at), I shall accept Dave's answer as the correct one. However your knowledge as per my comment above is excellent !!