# Keyboard shortcut to hide/show scrollbars?

Tags: ui, macos

I keep scrollbar visibility set to show only when scrolling. Nice and clean. Love it. Every once in a while, however, I need to grab a scrollbar.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle the hide/show status of scrollbars? If not a keyboard shortcut, is there a quicker way to get the scrollbars to appear (quicker than going into System Prefs every time, that is).

(*Yes, I know they appear temporarily when I'm scrolling.*)

Comment: HI @Sam - there's a command line way of achieving this in this older answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/100062

Comment: @MrR Ok! That’s a start!

Comment: You can set the scrollbar to be always shown. Tell me if tou want me to develop on how to do.